# How to bypass dotted abbreviations with awk?

Tags: c, awk

I have a line I want to separate into sentences using awk. I've set my field separator to '.' with `-F.` and used loop to print the grabbed sentences. But as expected it will also separate the dotted abbreviations.

For example, I have this line:

> I was born in 1990. Specifically Aug. 13, 1990. Etc etc etc.

What it does is it will output:

> I was born in 1990
>
> Specifically on Aug
>
> 13, 1990
>
> Etc etc etc

Even though what I want was:

> I was bon in 1990
>
> Specifically on Aug. 13, 1990
>
> Etc etc etc

What is the simplest method to bypass said abbreviations? Was a `.` for `-F` enough?

**EDIT**
Abbreviated words were months.

Comment: How are you supposed to detect whether something is an abbreviation? Do you have a list?

Comment: @Doorknob I just noticed the abbreviated words were just months. But I don't know how to incorporate a regex expression with awk.

Comment: If you know for sure that they'll only be months, you should [edit] that into your question so you can get a better answer.

Comment: awk -vRS='.' 'NF{sub("^ +","");print}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS='.' '{gsub(/^ +/,"")} /(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)$/{printf "%s. ",$0; next} /[^[:space:]]/{print $0 "."}' input.txt
I was born in 1990.
Specifically Aug. 13, 1990.
Etc etc etc.
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS='.'`

  Use the period as a record separator.
- `gsub(/^ +/,"")`

  Remove any leading spaces from records.
- `/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)$/{printf "%s. ",$0; next}`

  If a record ends with a month abbreviation, print the record followed by a period and a space but *no* newline.  Skip the remaining commands and jump to the `next` record.
- `/[^[:space:]]/{print $0 "."}`

  If the record contains any non-blanks, print it followed by a period.